# How Do I Add A Face to this mesh?

Tags: mesh, faces

[image]Ive been trying to make this shape (it was an SVG) but I cleaned up the mesh and deleted a lot of the mess, but now I need to make the faces clean to add into a boolian for a scene but I don't have much time, help would be appreciated. I added an image of the shape too

Comment: If you are short of time, go back to your original SVG, use the modifier *Decimate* (planar) and then *Solidify*.

Comment: If the mesh is cleaned up, why not simply make a large n-gon out of it? It's a myth that you always have to avoid n-gons at all costs.